# Why is my `` working sometimes and not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding attributes to element and it has styling to it. So I was able to add the html tags inside of ``. It is working sometimes and sometimes not.

When it is working:

```
$('.card-text')
  .text((size_avg).replace(/G/,'B'))
  .attr({
    'data-html': "true",
    'data-original-title': `<strong><u>Size: </u></strong> Number of Subscribers, <strong>`+ addCommas(Math.round(size_avg)) + `</strong>`
  });
```

The result for this is:

**Size:** Number of Subscribers, **11.5**

This works fine

But when I do this:

```
$('.card-text')
  .text(Math.round(act_sub).replace(/G/,'B'))
  .attr({
    'data-html': "true",
    'data-original-title': `<strong>yoyoyo</strong>`
  });
```

The result for this:

```
<strong>yoyoyo</strong>
```

Why is my code not working at the second time?

Comment: Any reason you are using backticks/template literals ( `` ) instead of standard quotes (' ' / " ")?

Comment: So you use `` but you do not use `${}` and still use string concatenation?

Comment: Do you have a running example. Hard to tell since it seems to be more about the library than the code.

Comment: How are you getting the result out of data original-title attribute? Maybe it has to do something with the way you r reading them back.

Comment: What is `siFormat`? I can't find a reference to it anywhere. I was trying to see how the different values passed in to this might affect the output.

Comment: @Lewis that is a function I wrote. Sorry. Let me take it out so it doesn't confuse anyone

Comment: Please create a runnable stack snippet ([Here's a guide if you don't know how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992))

Comment: @adiga Sure... let me try

Comment: @adiga I am not able to recreate this code. It is working like i said the first part works and the second part of the code is not working

Comment: Both parts of the code are working.  You are simply misunderstanding how template literals work.  `epascarello` in his first comment already pointed out the main issue.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry I missed your comment. I did not get it? WHat am I missing?

Comment: @Taplar Sorry I do not understand? Can you please explain?

Comment: [MDN Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is silly, but it is working for the second one when I add `data-html="true"` at the HTML part of the code instead of adding it to the JS.

HTML Code:

```
 <p class="card-text lg-metric-val" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">-</p>
```

And make the JS code:

```
$('.card-text')
   .text(Math.round(act_sub).replace(/G/,'B'))
   .attr({'data-original-title': `<strong>yoyoyo</strong>`
});
```

Its dumb but it is working. I don't know why it was working passing it as a jQuery attribute in one part of the code and not the other.

Thank you everyone!